# Git describe giving different tags

Tags: git, git-tag, git-describe

I have tagged my repository with the tag "Release_V1.0.0.4". But here is what I got from "git describe" and "git describe origin".

**[root pds_series]# git describe**

**Release_V1.0.0.2-22-g0859de9**

**[root pds_series]# git describe origin**

**Release_V1.0.0.2-18-gce2b24c**

With "git describe --all" and "git describe --tags" I got the right tag.

**[root pds_series]# git describe --all**

**tags/Release_v1.0.0.4**

**[root pds_series]# git describe --tags**

**Release_v1.0.0.4**

Also, with following command I got the right tag.

**[root pds_series]# git log --pretty=format:'%ad %h %d' --abbrev-commit --date=short -1**

**2012-11-15 0859de9  (HEAD, Release_v1.0.0.4, master)**

Do anyone know the reason behind this ? How can I resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably used a "lightweight" tag. By default `git describe` only uses tag objects to describe a commit whereas with `--tags` it will use any reference under `refs/tags` even if they point directly to a commit rather than a tag object.

To create a tag object you must use one of `-a` (annotated) or `-s` or `-u` (signed) options to `git tag`, otherwise a lightweight tag (a reference pointing straight to a commit) will be created.

To see the difference between your two tags try:

```
git cat-file -t Release_V1.0.0.2
```

and:

```
git cat-file -t Release_v1.0.0.4
```

On will probably say "tag" and the other will say "commit".

To resolve the issue you can recreate the tag with `-f` and (say) `-a`.

```
git tag -f -a Release_v1.0.0.4 Release_v1.0.0.4
```

Comment: Do I need to push after this ?