# Why is "git describe" showing an older tag version on my clean git repo copy?

Tags: git, tags, version, git-tag, git-describe

**Some background:**

I currently have two local git repos which point to the same origin/master project.  The reason I have two git repos is so that I have a clean master copy that I can use whenever I need and the one copy which my sandbox where I can apply changes, commit, etc.  It is probably overkill, but there are some advantages for me personally by having a duplicate local git copy.

A co-worker originally created a lightweight tag for 1.0.2, but we deleted it and re-tagged it as an annotated version with the same number.  They committed the change via git push to the remote repo.  I pulled down the latest changes on both my local git instances.

Our tags are as follows:

```
release-1.0.0
release-1.0.1
release-1.0.2
```

**The Problem:**

Here is the issue I can't figure out.  My sandbox repo shows the latest tag version (release-1.0.2) when I run "`git describe`".  This is what I expected.  However, the clean repo copy, which I only do pulls from, shows the older tag (release-1.0.1) when I execute "`git describe`".  I verified that both are pointing to the origin master.  I did some more research and found an [overstack solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13412713/2532191) that pointed me to running "git cat-file -t".  Here is the difference I noticed:

```
git cat-file -t release-1.0.1 --> tag 
git cat-file -t release-1.0.2 --> commit
```

Why is my clean copy repo showing an older tag version when I run "`git describe`" unlike my sandbox repo? I can confirm that I can see release-1.0.2 listed if I run "`git describe --tags`" on the clean repo copy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> A co-worker originally created a lightweight tag for 1.0.2, but we deleted it and re-tagged it as an annotated version with the same number. They committed the change via git push to the remote repo. I pulled down the latest changes on both my local git instances.

Unless you use the `--tags` flag, `git describe` is only concerned with *[annotated](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging#Annotated-Tags)* (as opposed to *[lightweight](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging#Lightweight-Tags)*) tags. Here, the output of `git cat-file` indicates that you still have the old `release-1.0.2` lightweight tag in your sandbox repo. The snag is that, by default, `git pull` itself will not fetch the newer, annotated tag of the same name and overwrite the older, lightweight one with it.

To solve the problem, first delete the lightweight tag locally by running

```
git tag -d release-1.0.2
```

in your sandbox repo, and then, run

```
git fetch
```

(or `git pull`, if you know what you're doing). The new `release-1.0.2` annotated tag will then take the place of the old lightweight one. You can make sure of that by running `git describe` or

```
git cat-file -t release-1.0.2
```

which should now output `tag` (not `commit`).

Comment: That would explain why my clean repo is showing an older tag, but doesn't explain why my sandbox repo is showing the latest (lightweight) tag when I run 'git describe'.  I noticed in my eclipse git view, that the older tag is displayed as as annotated (little yellow person icon) and the newer tag is displayed as lightweight [See "Light-weight and Signed Tags"](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Tagging).  My co-worker originally created a lightweight tag for 1.0.2, but we deleted it and retagged it as an annotated version with the same number.  Could that be messing things up?

Comment: @lifesabeach *My co-worker originally created a lightweight tag for 1.0.2, but we deleted it and retagged it as an annotated version with the same number. Could that be messing things up?* Yes. Everything indicates that you still have the old lightweight tag `release-1.0.2` in your sandbox repo. The snag is that, by default, `git pull` itself will not fetch the new annotated one and overwrite the old lightweight one with it. Try deleting the tag locally with `git tag -d release-1.0.2`, then run `git pull`. Then check the situation with `git describe`.

Comment: @lifesabeach By the way, [your comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32209616/why-is-git-describe-showing-an-older-tag-version-on-my-clean-git-repo-copy#comment52304969_32209958) contains useful information for answering your question. For completeness, you should edit your question and add that information there. Then your question (and answers to it) will be more likely to help future visitors.

Comment: Thanks @Jubobs.  That worked! I made the respective updates to my original question and your original response.

Comment: @lifesabeach Cool. I've edited my answer accordingly.