# Why is git describe returning a super old tag?

Tags: git, git-tag, git-describe

I’m fairly new to using `git describe`.

Shouldn’t `git describe`, return the last tag that you get from git tag? I currently get `tag-release-1.0.1-2107-g4a123293e` (from 4yrs ago) returned when I do `git describe`. I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32209616/why-is-git-describe-showing-an-older-tag-version-on-my-clean-git-repo-copy) question, but I get the same result when I run it with `--tags`.

I ask because `git tag` for me returns something like this. I suppose because we changed the tagging convention the sorting is messed up and so is `git describe`.

```
3.23
3.24
...
4.14
4.15 (most recent tag)
...
tag-release-1.0.0
tag-release-1.0.1 (from 4 yrs ago)
```

Is my thought process correct here?

Comment: Hard to answer without seeing the repository, because the answer depends on the history between your current `HEAD` and the tags. Are the commits referred to by the more recent tags reachable from your HEAD, or are they on another branch?

Comment: I'm **almost** 100% certain all the 3.* 4.* versions are reachable from the current checked out branch. **Surprisingly** when I do `git merge-base --is-ancestor 4.15.0 HEAD; echo $?` I get `1`. When I do: `git merge-base --is-ancestor tag-release-1.0.1 HEAD; echo $?` I get `0`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: That tells us that tag `4.15.0.1661270148` is not reachable from (is not an ancestor of) your `HEAD`, which is why it's not being considered by `git describe`. That's about all we can say without seeing your repository history.

Comment: @larsks That's super weird. Is there a way to visualize how they diverged? or gain some more information?

Comment: "Is there a way to visualize how they diverged?" Yes, almost *any* Git-GUI will visualize commit's DAG

Comment: @larsks I figured it out. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've been tagging on release branches.
What exacerbates the problem is that almost every time we cherry-pick into the release branches as well. ‍♂️

Upon every commit to a release branch, we re-tag.

Given that the tags happen after commits on **release** branch, example on release/4.15.0, then since the main (master) branch doesn't have those commits, `git describe` won't be able to bridge the gap.

**Solution:**

Tag on **main** branch only.

Comment: fwiw : `git log --simplify-by-decoration` is a good way to see how branches or tags relate one to another : `git log --graph --oneline --simplify-by-decoration --all`